# What are the differences between a compressor wash on wing vs on test bed

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-maintenance, engine

I work in an aircraft engine overhaul facility and I’m trying to understand the process of compressor washing engines on Wing compared to washing them in a test bed. What process steps are different on wing? Are there time/noise restrictions on wing? The cost of washing an engine on wing? Who completes the comp washes?

Comment: You may transform the title in a question as this is a Q&A website